# Split List with a List of delimiters

Tags: python-2.7

```
list1 = [185, 184, 183, 182, 181, 180, 179, 178, 207, 177, 176, 206, 175, 174, 173, 172, 171, 170, 169, 205, 168, 167, 166, 165, 164, 163, 162, 161, 160, 159, 158, 157, 156, 204, 155, 154, 153, 152, 151, 150, 149, 148, 147, 146, 145, 144, 143, 203, 142, 141, 140, 139, 138, 137, 136, 135, 134, 133, 132, 131, 130, 202, 129, 128, 127, 126, 125, 124, 123, 122, 121, 120, 119, 118, 117, 201, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 200, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 199, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 198, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 197, 11, 196, 10, 9, 8]

delim = [182, 175, 164, 151, 138, 125, 112, 99, 86, 73, 60, 47, 34, 21, 11]
```

How can I split the list, with the delim list and still keep the delim values?

the result I'm looking for is

newList = [ [185,184, 183], [182, 181, 180, 179, 178, 207, 177, 176, 206], [175, 174 .......

I have to use Python 2.7, because the "Main" application I'm automating for is still using 2.7 for its scripting language

I'm not sure how to get a loop to change what item it uses in the 'delim' list when it 'hits' the previous item in the 'delim' list

edit: OK I'm getting close.... just have to solve a IndexError

```
newList, currList, currDelimIndex = [], [], 0
for i in list1:
    if i == delim[currDelimIndex]:
        newList.append(currList)
        currDelimIndex += 1
        currList = [i]
    else:
        currList.append(i)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "split the list with the delim list"! What does that mean? Please **edit** your question to clearly define that, and explain what you've tried so far.

Comment: What should be the result? What happened when you tried it? Why did you not use a simple `for` loop?

Comment: (it might also be helpful clearly defining why you need to do this on [tag:python-2.7], since Python 2k is generally not supported any more, and you seem to have a special use case. Some answers might simply not work for you because of that, and the potential answerers can have no idea about it, because you're not explaining your constraints!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with,  if anyone has a better solution, feel free to share

```
list1 = [185, 184, 183, 182, 181, 180, 179, 178, 207, 177, 176, 206, 175, 174, 173, 172, 171, 170, 169, 205, 168, 167, 166, 165, 164, 163, 162, 161, 160, 159, 158, 157, 156, 204, 155, 154, 153, 152, 151, 150, 149, 148, 147, 146, 145, 144, 143, 203, 142, 141, 140, 139, 138, 137, 136, 135, 134, 133, 132, 131, 130, 202, 129, 128, 127, 126, 125, 124, 123, 122, 121, 120, 119, 118, 117, 201, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 200, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 199, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 198, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 197, 11, 196, 10, 9, 8]

delim = [182, 175, 164, 151, 138, 125, 112, 99, 86, 73, 60, 47, 34, 21, 11]
newList, currList, currDelimIndex = [], [], 0
for edge in list1:
    if edge == delim [currDelimIndex]:
        newList.append(currList)
        if currDelimIndex < len(delim) - 1:
            currDelimIndex += 1
        currList = [edge]
    else:
        currList.append(edge)
newList.append(currList)  # append the last group
```